# How to create a new column in multiindex dataframe which is in the format of datetime, using a reference date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, multi-index

How to create a new column in a multi index dataframe which has the dates in each row representing the dates from the reference time. for eg.

THE REFRENCE TIME IS **10:30am** everyday.

*delta_minutes* column represent how much time is before the REFERENCE TIME?
**For eg. the row where the delta_mins=20  for date 2019-12-2 means that the actual time for that particular row is 10:10am 2019-12-2 which is 20 minutes behind the reference time**

I want to add another column which is an indication of what actual time that row indicates so that i can model it in a time series
df1 is the actual df while the new datframe that i want to generate looks like df2

df1

```
date      delta_mins   sold_before
2019-12-2   20            a1  
            30            a2  
            40            a3    
            50            a4  
            60            a5  
2019-12-3   20            d1  
            30            d2  
            40            d3  
            50            d4  
            60            d5  
2019-12-4   20            g1  
            30            g2  
            40            g3  
            50            g4  
            60            g5
```

REFERENCE TIME = 10:30 am

df2

```
date      delta_mins   sold_before     actual_time
2019-12     20            a1          2019-12-2 10:10
            30            a2          2019-12-2 10:00
            40            a3          2019-12-2 09:50
            50            a4          2019-12-2 09:40
            60            a5          2019-12-2 09:30          
2019-12-3   20            d1          2019-12-3 10:10  
            30            d2          2019-12-3 10:00
            40            d3          2019-12-3 09:50
            50            d4          2019-12-3 09:40
            60            d5          2019-12-3 09:30
2019-12-4   20            g1          2019-12-4 10:10
            30            g2          2019-12-4 10:00
            40            g3          2019-12-4 09:50
            50            g4          2019-12-4 09:40
            60            g5          2019-12-4 09:30
```

Comment: Isn’t this just a difference and a sum?

Comment: But it is in  a multiindex df, and i cant get my head around how to do using multiindex

Comment: Is the df1 a result of a `groupby()` function?

Comment: yes @davidbilla

Comment: @VishalAnand I was caught up in some other stuff, see my answer below. Hope this helps. Let me know if I missed anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `reset_index()` and apply your operation

```
df1 = df1.reset_index(drop=True)
df1['actual_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['date'] + ' 10:30:00') - df1['delta_mins'].apply(lambda x:  pd.Timedelta(minutes=x))
```

if `df1['date']` is of dtype `datetime64` then convert it to string before concate

```
df1['actual_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') + ' 10:30:00') - df1['delta_mins'].apply(lambda x:  pd.Timedelta(minutes=x))
```

Output:

```
         date  delta_mins sold_before         actual_time
0   2019-12-2          20          a1 2019-12-02 10:10:00
1   2019-12-2          30          a2 2019-12-02 10:00:00
2   2019-12-2          40          a3 2019-12-02 09:50:00
3   2019-12-2          50          a4 2019-12-02 09:40:00
4   2019-12-2          60          a5 2019-12-02 09:30:00
5   2019-12-3          20          d1 2019-12-03 10:10:00
6   2019-12-3          30          d2 2019-12-03 10:00:00
7   2019-12-3          40          d3 2019-12-03 09:50:00
8   2019-12-3          50          d4 2019-12-03 09:40:00
9   2019-12-3          60          d5 2019-12-03 09:30:00
10  2019-12-4          20          g1 2019-12-04 10:10:00
11  2019-12-4          30          g2 2019-12-04 10:00:00
12  2019-12-4          40          g3 2019-12-04 09:50:00
13  2019-12-4          50          g4 2019-12-04 09:40:00
14  2019-12-4          60          g5 2019-12-04 09:30:00
```

Once you have it then use your `df1.groupby()` statement to group the data again if you need it.

```
df1 = df1.groupby(['date', 'delta_mins', 'sold_before']).agg(lambda x: x) # replace this with your groupby() statement
```

Output:

```
                                         actual_time
date      delta_mins sold_before                    
2019-12-2 20         a1          2019-12-02 10:10:00
          30         a2          2019-12-02 10:00:00
          40         a3          2019-12-02 09:50:00
          50         a4          2019-12-02 09:40:00
          60         a5          2019-12-02 09:30:00
2019-12-3 20         d1          2019-12-03 10:10:00
          30         d2          2019-12-03 10:00:00
          40         d3          2019-12-03 09:50:00
          50         d4          2019-12-03 09:40:00
          60         d5          2019-12-03 09:30:00
2019-12-4 20         g1          2019-12-04 10:10:00
          30         g2          2019-12-04 10:00:00
          40         g3          2019-12-04 09:50:00
          50         g4          2019-12-04 09:40:00
          60         g5          2019-12-04 09:30:00
```

OR:

You can use `.transform()` in your `groupby()` statement to expand the date column to all the rows and then apply the operation for 'actual_time'